# ¿Es std::function equivalente a un puntero?

Tags: c++, c++11

Estaba practicando con lambdas y me encontré con el siguiente código:

```
auto make_fibo() {
    return [](int n) {
        std::function<int(int)> recurse;

        recurse = [&](int n) {
            return (n <= 2) ? 1 : recurse(n - 1) + recurse(n - 2);
        };

        return recurse(n);
    };
}
```

Yo no sabia que era `function` ni como trabajaba después de buscar y leer varios textos por ejemplo el siguiente:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/

Mi pregunta es si, `std::function` es similar a lo siguiente por ejemplo:

```
typedef int (*FredMemFn)(int i);
```

Comment: Sugerencia: edita el título para que sea más autocontenido: Por ejemplo: "¿Es std::function equivalente a un puntero?" (o a un typedef, o lo que sea más apropiado)

Comment: La pregunta es si `std::function` es similar a un puntero a función, o a un `typedef` de un puntero a función?

Comment: `¿Es std::function equivalente a un puntero?` No, no lo es. `Mi pregunta es si, std::function es similar a lo siguiente ...` Puede ser.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

La respuesta es sí. La cuestión es que **function<>** es capaz de manejar más casos que el de ser un simple puntero a una función. Por ejemplo, puede cubrir también el caso de *functor*, es decir, el caso de una clase con el operador () sobrecargado. Fíjate en el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int doble(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}

class Doblador {
public:
    int operator()(int x) {
        return x * 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    Doblador d;
    function<int(int)> f = doble;

    cout << "Doble de 2 = " << f( 2 ) << endl;

    f = d;
    cout << "Doble de 2 = " << f( 2 ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Tienes el código aquí: http://ideone.com/5lALLH
Espero que te resulte útil.

Comment: Mereces mas likes. Nunca mejor respondido.

Comment: Si function<> es capaz de manejar más casos que un puntero a función entonces no son equivalentes. No se si dar un -1 siendo estricto o un +1 porque se entiende perfectamente la explicación, es correcta y tiene un buen ejemplo... ...No hay que pasarse de estricto, +1.

Comment: La diferencia es que es mucho más lento, incluso más lento que una función virtual, debido a que `std::function` implementa (que yo sepa) *type erasure*, que añade un nivel de indireción extra a las llamadas: https://ibob.github.io/dynamix/advanced.html#performance

Answer (score 4):

`std::function` es una clase que envuelve a cualquier elemento que pueda ser invocado, por ejemplo:

- Punteros a funciones (lo que se menciona en la pregunta).
- Objetos de una clase que tiene el operador `()` sobrecargado.
- Expresiones lambda.
- Expresiones bind (`std::bind`, básicamente un puntero a función con uno o más argumentos predefinidos de antemano).

Fuente: [cppreference.com - std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Nótese que las funciones "template" no son invocables como tal, solo una instancia en particular de una función template con un tipo ya asociado puede combinarse con un `std::function`.